# MySql Indexing for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, indexing, typeorm

My table contains columns c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 , I have  more than 64 combination of queries like this

my queries are

1. `where (c1=1 and c2=2 and c3=3)`
2. `where (c1=1 and c2=2 and c3=3 and c4 =4 and c5 =5 )`
3. `where (c1=1 and c2=2 and c3=3 and c4=4)`
4. `where (c1=1 and c2=2 and c3=3 and c6)`
5. `where ( c2=2 and c3=3)` ..etc

I created index for multiple columns using this query

```sql
create INDEX `allpair` ON TABLE_NAME (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6);
```

but it's not working for all combinations
Should I need to add indexes for all combinations?

Comment: keep in mind that the order is important. if your index starts with c1, any where clause not including c1 will not benefit from that index. think of it like a phone book sorted by last name, then first name. only searching for the first name won’t benefit from that order at all

Comment: You can't possibly index all combinations. You might find that your schema isn't going to work, and you may need to restructure, or create a derivative schema that's far more relational so you can work with it. I've done this before where you create separated look-up tables, something along the lines of a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema). These are super annoying to work with in the course of regular operations, but are really fast to query.

Comment: *Should I need to add indexes for all combinations?* It depends. If the query speed is critical then the index for this query improvement must be created. From the practice - the amount of such **really** critical queries is low, 2-3, not more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good answer.

The index you propose helps some with any query involving `c1=constant`, but does not help if that is missing.  And, the farther you get into that multi-column index, the less useful the columns become.  That is, your `allpair` is useless for your query 5.

A partial answer:

- build a "few" 2- or 3-column indexes.
- focus on columns that are likely to be tested `=constant`; this is because "range" tests do not optimize as well.
- tend to start the various indexes with different first columns
- look at the likely queries -- you will probably find a string bias in what columns are tested.  In real estate, most queries include 'number of bedrooms' but do not include 'has gazebo'.

If you had *just* those 5 queries, then `INDEX(c2,c3,c1)` (or `INDEX(c3,c2,c1)`) would be perhaps best.

You cannot provide all combos.  There is a hard limit of 64 indexes on a table.  5-10 is a *practical* limit.

Are the constants numbers?  Do you need "ranges" of numbers?  Are some of them strings?  [If you have over-simplified the question by showing only `=number`, you are preventing me from providing some other solutions.]

**More**

- Ranges (`>`, `BETWEEN`, `!=`, `LIKE 'abc%'`, sometimes `IN`, etc) -- The index won't go past that column.  So, tend to put such columns at the end of a composite index.
- 2 ranges in a `WHERE` -- The Optimizer will decide which one to use; usually it will pick the better one.
- `FOREIGN KEY` -- This is a combination of a constraint that is used when `INSERTing` and `INDEX` that may be useful for `SELECT`.  When adding an FK, if there is already a useful `INDEX`, the FK won't add a redundant index.
- Strings (`VARCHAR`, not `TEXT`) -- Think of them similar to numbers when it comes to indexing.
- `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` (etc) -- These are, shall we say, glorified numbers.  However, they are usually used as a "range".
- Numbers, string, and dates all can be involved in either `=` or range tests.  My index advice applies equally to each.

More on indexing:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and perhaps [*Entity-Attribute-Value*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Comment: Yes, values will be ranges, strings, and foreign keys also, Please explain those cases.

Comment: @AbhishekP - I added some info.  What I added does not invalidate what I had already said.  If you would like to make a try at the indexes, I will advise further.  But _do_ use real column names.